# Is there a clang analogue of gcc's `__attribute__((hot))`

Tags: clang, compiler-optimization, clang++

I wish to mark a function for more aggressive optimizations. The function is not called often, so PGO won't help, but I still want it as low latency as possible.

gcc has attribute `hot` for this. Is there some clang equivalent I'm missing?

BTW clang does accept `__attribute__((hot))`, but AFAICT it has zero impact (and is undocumented). Probably for source compatibility with gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Writing an answer instead of deleting, in case it is of use to others)

So turns out that since December 2020 [Clang *does* support `__attribute__((hot))`](https://reviews.llvm.org/rG3733463dbb58a29892be3872bd32f93cb9af492c), they just didn't document it. I [nudged](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53808) them.  When tested in a newer clang version I see a difference in binaries.

BTW they did support `__attribute__((cold))` long before that. And as I suspected, the clang front end did accept `hot` [for sake of gcc compatibility](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/rfc-add-hot-function-attribute-to-llvm-ir-and-use-hot-cold-attribute-in-function-section-prefix/57103).

Comment: Usually for attributes clang doesn't support, it prints a warning.  So it doesn't need to accept + ignore them.